# Add microdata to asynchronously loaded content

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous, seo, schema.org, microdata

I am currently working on a Wordpress based website for our modelling agency. We are using the [Photolux photography template](http://themeforest.net/item/photolux-photography-portfolio-wordpress-theme/894193). Also, [here's](http://pexetothemes.com/demos/photolux_wp/) a demo of the theme.

I am trying to implement [schema.org's microdata](http://schema.org/) to boost our SEO rating, but I can't really figure out how can I add the required microdata to the images that are loaded asynchronously. Also, I don't really know if adding microdata to that async content will help regarding SEO... If not, what can we do to improve our SEO rating where the content is asynchronously loaded via javascript?

Comment: Note that discussing SEO is off-topic on SO, so you should omit questions like "if […] will help regarding SEO" and "what can we do to improve our SEO". If you want to ask about these topics, [webmasters.se] might be suitable.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know that. I'll post the question there.

Comment: If you think you can remove the SEO advice aspect from this question, [edit] it. Otherwise, the whole question could be migrated to Webmasters (I think you could flag it for moderator attention then).